# Use .htaccess to redirect to http://www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So in the browsers my domain appears like this: `www.mysite.com`. But I want to achieve the following: `http://www.mysite.com`. Currently the desired result works in IE only (tested in IE11). Chrome and FF will show the URL as `www.mysite.com`. Is it possible to have `http://www.mysite.com` in the address bar of all browsers?

Comment: The browsers generally don't show `http` or `https` in address bar.

Comment: This sounds like a browser setting so I don't think there I anything you can do except go visit all of your clients and manually change all of their browser settings.

Comment: I think browsers hides this prefix on purpose. When you copy the link it contains the prefix.

Comment: @hjpotter92 it may not show `http` but it will definitely show `https`.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome will remove the **http://** from the address bar (Probably for readability). I assume FF would do the same as may some others.

Comment: Maybe you're right I've found this: http://support.mozilla.org/bg/questions/879926 ... But I still don't know why did they remove the protocol?

Comment: **Https** is shown on chrome if the site has an SSL certificate. Not really any need to show **http* as every site that doesn't have SSL will use this protocol.